# How to create a new shapefile name for each scheduled task using a Python script

Tags: python

I just created a simple python script that goes through a folder with polyline shapefiles and merges them. Through the Windows 8 Task Scheduler I have scheduled the script to run when I want.

All I would like to do now is modify my script so I can slightly change the name of each shapefile output. For example, the script name for Week 1 would be MergedTracks_1, for Week 2 would be MergedTracks_2, for Week 3 would be MergedTracks_3, etc..

Does anybody have an idea on how to do this with the current script I have? I am running ArcGIS 10.2. I would appreciate any insight if possible. Below is the script I am currently using in PythonWin.  Thanks so much in advance!!!

```
import arcpy, os  

outPut = r"C:\Users\student2\Desktop\WeedTracksMergeScript\Output" # Output  
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\student2\Desktop\WeedTracksMergeScript" 
shplist =  arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('*.shp')
print shplist # prints polyline .shp list in current arcpy.env.workspace
arcpy.Merge_management(shplist, os.path.join(outPut, "MergedTracks_1.shp"))  
print "Done"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pickle to keep track of the last filename that was written, and then use that as part of your logic to determine what the next filename format should be.

Check out the tutorial here:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle

The main idea would be to do something like this:

Here is some pseudocode:

```
load pickle file

if pickle file exists
    load pickle file
    use logic to increment new filename
else:
    use default file name

do logic for your work and write with set file name

write to pickle file for the new file name
```

Here is a quick example on how to use pickle:

```
import pickle
from os.path import exists

pickle_file = "current_file_name.pickle"

if exists(pickle_file):
    with open(pickle_file, "rb") as pkr:
        current_filename = pickle.load(pkr)
else:
    current_filename = "current_file_1"

with open(pickle_file, "wb") as pkw:
    pickle.dump(current_filename, pkw)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think datetime stamps (strings) would be a lot less complicated and arguably more useful.

Many formatting options are documented at http://strftime.org

```
import datetime
dd = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")
shpfile = os.path.join(out_path), "MergedTracks_{}.shp".format(dd))
arcpy.Merge_management(shplist, shpfile)
```

Comment: You need to remove the closing bracket immediate after "out_path".